# Can chestnut mean a short article?

Tags: meaning, expressions

There's [this article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/18/business/media/dylan-newest-nobel-laureate-maintains-his-reticence.html?rref=collection%2Ftimestopic%2FDylan%2C%20Bob&action=click&contentCollection=timestopics&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=latest&contentPlacement=3&pgtype=collection) on the NY Times about Dylan's nomination for the Nobel Laureate last week. In it the authors say

> Mr. Dylan’s set at that show was almost identical to that of the first weekend, with an intriguing addition: “Why Try to Change Me Now?,” a chestnut written by Cy Coleman and Joseph McCarthy that Mr. Dylan included on his 2015 album “Shadows in the Night.”

I took *chestnut* to be a short article. Article because of the context, short from the expression *in a nutshell*. Is that correct?

Comment: The context implies that, as Bob Dylan is a songwriter and that the object in question was added to his performance set and added to one of his albums of music, and therefore is most likely another song. [The etymology of chestnut](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chestnut) most likely does not involve 'nutshell'.

Comment: The chestnut is found on an album, so it has to do with music. If you check  the disambiguations for chestnut on Wikipedia, you will find [this entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chestnut_(joke)), and it takes you to chestnut (joke), but also refers to chestnut (music).

Comment: Most often an "old chestnut" is a brief saying or joke which is well-known and fondly regarded, even if it's a bit trite and corny.  Though I've only rarely heard the term applied to music, I would assume that the same criteria apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old story/song.

From Mirriam/Webster

> **Full Definition of chestnut**
>
> **1**
> *a :*   any of a genus (Castanea) of trees or shrubs of the beech family; especially :   an American tree (C. dentata) that was formerly a dominant or codominant member of many deciduous forests of the eastern United States but has now been largely eliminated by the chestnut blight and seldom grows beyond the shrub or sapling stage
>
> *b :*   the edible nut of a chestnut
>
> *c :*   the wood of a chestnut
>
> **2**  a grayish to reddish brown
>
> **3**  horse chestnut
>
> **4**  a chestnut-colored animal; specifically :   a horse having a body color of any shade of pure or reddish brown with mane, tail, and points of the same or a lighter shade
>
> **5** a callosity on the inner side of the leg of the horse — see horse illustration
>
> **6**
> *a :*   **an old joke or story**
>
> *b :*   something (as a musical piece or a saying) repeated to the point of staleness

[Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chestnut)

Comment: Definition 6.b seems more appropriate that 6.a.

Comment: Perhaps there is also a little wry comment given the last lines of the song are "Don't you remember I was always your clown?
Why try to change me now?"